# How to add cache control on a static file which have a http code 404

Tags: nginx, caching, static, http-status-code-404

I would like to add http header `Cache-Control: max-age=4` on non existing static file.

I try to include the following block into my nginx vhost

```
server {
    listen *:80;
    server_name local.test.com;
    root /vat/www/test;

    location ~*  \.(js)$ {
      expires 4s;
    }
}
```

On an existing asset it work fine

```
curl -s -I http://local.test.com/index.js | grep Cache-Control

Cache-Control: max-age=4
```

On a none existing asset it does't work

```
curl -s -I http://local.test.com/fake.js

HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: nginx/1.15.8
Date: Thu, 19 Sep 2019 09:10:39 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 153
Connection: keep-alive
```

Any idea ?

Comment: file not found , why you need cache header for not found url !!

Comment: it's not logic , to add header for file not found , you may to redirect for 404 page .. you can also using varnish to cache redirect . to save that process